# CakePHP 2: How to store answer session of multiple choice

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I want to store user selected answer from multiple choice questions like in this image:

[image]

I have trouble when user update their answer in another question id.
I use url parameter when passing user answer, then process it in server side using ajax request.

Here are my code:

```
//php code in server side
$answer[] = array(
        'questionItemId' => $questionItemId, 
        'choice' => $choice
    );
    $newSession = array();

    if(!$this->Session->check('answerChoice')) {
        $this->Session->write('answerChoice', $answer);
    } else {
        $sessionChoice = $this->Session->read('answerChoice');
        foreach($sessionChoice as $itemChoice) {
            if($itemChoice['questionItemId'] == $questionItemId) {
                if($itemChoice['choice'] != $choice) {
                    $newSession[] = array(
                        'questionItemId' => $questionItemId, 
                        'choice' => $choice
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        $this->Session->write('answerChoice', $newSession);
    }
    debug($this->Session->read('answerChoice'));

//ajax js in client side
$('#choiceA, #choiceB, #choiceC, #choiceD').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + 'ajaxed_handlers/refresh_answer/' + $(this).attr('question-item-id') + '/' + $(this).val(),
        success:function(data){
            $('#theform').html(data); //refresh answer done list
        }
    });
});
```

Debug Result like in this picture :

Picture Question number 1
[image]

Picture Question number 2
[image]

Any help very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What trouble do you have? You have to describe that for others to be able to help you along.

Comment: Hi, when user select new answer by click on radio box in the next question, I want to store it then merge it with previous answer in previous question. Also, user should be able to change their answer in any question number by go to next/prev slide. Ex: question number 1 has chosed A as answer, then go to next slide in number 2 with B as answer, but user should be able to change their answer in any question number.

Comment: Ok, that is what you want to achieve, but where does it fail you: At what point do you still have your data, and at what point not anymore. (Also you "hi, when" comment; Update your main question with that using the edit, that helps other viewers: The better the question looks, the better chance on an answer).

Comment: Thanks for advice Norbert. I just updated my question with 2 picture. Its Question number 1 with debug result when user click on radio A as answer, then click next button to continue Question number 2 with C as answer. But see the result, the debug Session is empty. Its sould still have first answer with second answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done for this question. I changed the way to store answer from session to submit form from ajax request.

Thank you for attention.